# Shift-reduce and reduce-reduce conflicts with LR

Tags: compiler-construction, shift-reduce-conflict, reduce-reduce-conflict

This is the grammar:

```
expr-> expr OPER expr
expr->PREFIX expr
expr->expr POSTFIX
expr->expr ‘?’ expr ‘:’ expr
expr->expr‘[’ expr ‘]’
expr->expr‘(’ expr ‘)’
expr->ID
expr->CONSTANT
expr->‘(’ expr‘)
```

I cannot find the shift-reduce and reduce-reduce conflicts with LR, can someone help me?

Comment: How do you parse `PREFIX ID POSTFIX`, precisely?

Answer (score 0):

The priority of the operators:
1)[] () . –> POSTFIX ++ –– (LEFT Customerism)
2)PREFIX ++ –– -
3)?: (RIGHT CUSTOMERISM)

Comment: I'm not sure what this is, but it is definitely not an answer. Perhaps you intended to [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66186113/edit), although you would also want to do a better job of [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)